# How to mention a user in a Chatter Group in an Apex Trigger?

Tags: chatter, feeditem, chatter-groups

How to mention a user in a Chatter Group in an Apex Trigger?

There are similar questions existing in SFSE but they all seem to have outdated answers using old cumbersome APIs. I believe the easiest way is to use the `FeedItem` object. I have only managed to send a message to a user (not the same as an "@" mention) and share with the company using the below code. Documentation is scanty regarding how to mention a user in a Chatter Group.

```
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = u.Id;
post.Body = 'Please find the download URL herewith.';
post.Title = 'User Guide';
post.LinkUrl = 'https://c.cs7.content.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/068M0000000CvrF';
feedItemList.add(post);
```

Comment: Considering that now with Winter '14 we can also mention Chatter Group names to post to groups, how can we mention multiple items (Chatter Group + User) in an Apex Trigger?

Answer (score 5):

Chatter in apex (ConnectApi) was designed for this type of coding:

```
ConnectApi.FeedType feedType = ConnectApi.FeedType.UserProfile;

ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment;
ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegment = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();

messageInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegment.text = 'Hey there ';
messageInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

mentionSegment.id = '005D0000001LLO1';
messageInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegment);

textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegment.text = '. How are you?';
messageInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

input.body = messageInput;

ConnectApi.FeedItem feedItemRep = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(communityId, feedType, 'me', input, null);
```

In this case the mentionSegment.id would be your group id. Full documentation of the ConnectApi can be found here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_connect_api.htm

Comment: Excellent Answer.  Beat me to it  :)

Comment: In addition, we've provided a helper Apex class that you can use to make it easier to post mentions. You can get it from github (https://github.com/alouie-sfdc/ConnectApiHelper), and there's a blog post about it too (http://www.bridgefarmconsulting.com/blog/new-helper-classes-for-working-with-the-connectapi/).